# Clicar em um item e enviar para a pagina especifica

Tags: ionic, angular

sou novo no ionic e queria uma dica de vocês . Possou uma lista fixa no meu app com os serviços que ele disponhe apos cria essa lista na view principal gostaria de ao clicar em determinado item ela fosse para a página da sua determinada função.
 Quando eu clicar em carro na tela ele envia para a tela com as especificações.

Sei que tem o NavController , porém não estou conseguindo fazer .

qualquer ajuda é válida =)

Exemplo

```
this.opcoes = [
        {nome:'carro'},
        {nome:'moto'},
        {nome:'barco'},
        {nome:'aviões'},
       ];
  }
```

Oque eu tentei :

```
import{ carro } from '../escolha/carro';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  public opcoes;

 //public String op = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    this.opcoes = [
        {nome:'carro'},
        {nome:'moto'},
        {nome:'barco'},
        {nome:'aviões'},

    ];
  }
  goToPage() {
    this.opcoes[0] = this.navCtrl.setRoot(carro);
 }
```

Comment: Mostre o que você tentou até agora.

Comment: editei a pergunta lucas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export class HomePage {  
     opcoes: Array<any> = [];  

.... }

constructor() {

this.opcoes.push({name:'Carros',function:'novoCarro' }); this.opcoes.push({name:'Motos',function:'novaMoto'});

}  

novoCarro(){ this.navCtrl.push(NomePaginaCarros); }

novaMoto(){ this.navCtrl.push(NomePaginaMoto); }
```

Comment: Explique o que fez, assim já facilita muito. Só postar o código fica confuso as vezes.

Comment: Minha resposta foi baseada no código que ele colocou, ele vai entender exatamente como fazer se olhar os passos do código.

Comment: Mas pode ter terceiros que não entendam. Se pode colocar explicado, porque não colocar!? Fica um negócio simplesmente jogado, mal indentado, etc... Não custa fazer bem feito.